# My location never changes on map even if i change the lat/long in the code

Tags: openlayers

Location never changes, even with changed lat/long location.

Can someone suggest to me what needs to be done?

```
var geojsonObject = {

  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.0107421875,
          5.703447982149503
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: 
  (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'})
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  // style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 8.34],
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

Comment: Which location you want to change? The view.center property or the location of the geojson object? In case you test it on your local machine, did you try deleting the cache before reloading your file(s)?

Comment: Can you provide some example locations?